# Undefined method `simple_field_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fa76a658768>:0x007fa76a962d50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm attempting to use the cocoon gem to created some nested forms mixed with simple form and I get getting `Undefined method simple_field_for` when I implement the form. I'm fairly new to rails so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid fix but I've scanned Stack Overflow and Google long enough where I've decided to just post and ask. The tutorial I'm following uses haml in the views. Below is my code, please let me know if something else needs to be posted to assist with the error. Thank you!

**Total Error Message:**

```
undefined method `simple_field_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fa76a658768>:0x007fa76a962d50>

.row
   .col-md-6
     %h3 Ingredients
     #ingredients
      = f.simple_field_for :ingredients do |ingredient| #this is the line throwing the error
        = render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients, class: 'btn btn-default add-button'
```

**Partial File Throwing The Error: _form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    - if @recipe.errors.any?
        #errors
          %p
           = @recipe.errors.count
           Prevented this recipe from saving.
          %ul
           - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
             %li= msg
    .panel-body
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
        = f.input :image, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        .row
          .col-md-6
            %h3 Ingredients
            #ingredients
              = f.simple_field_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
                = render 'ingredients_fields', f: ingredient
              .links
                = link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients, class: 'btn btn-default add-button'

    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

**Ingredient Field Partial: _ingredients_fields.html.haml**

```
.form-inline.clearfix
    .nested-fields
        = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-input form-control' }
        = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: 'form-button btn btn-default'
```

Again, let me know if any other files need to be included. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `simple_fields_for`, not `simple_field_for`. You are missing `s`.

Read [Simple Form Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for more info.